# Needed help to totally remove Temp tables oracle procedures - Oracle - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myDemoStoreProc
    (  
      inputVariable1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0 ,
      v_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )

    AS

    BEGIN

       INSERT INTO temptable1( 
        SELECT DISTINCT FROM TABLE1 
         WHERE  Col1 = 'logic1' );

       INSERT INTO temptable2( 
        SELECT col2 ,
               NVL(( SELECT col1
                     FROM temptable1 tt1
                      WHERE  sm.col1 = tt1.col1), 0) col3,
               col4
          FROM table2 sm);

       DELETE temptable2
        WHERE  col4 IN ( 'logic2','logic3' )
                 OR col4 IS NULL;

       IF NVL(inputVariable1 , 0) = 1 THEN
        DELETE temptable2
        WHERE  col1!= 'logic4';
       END IF;

       OPEN  v_cursor FOR
          SELECT col1,
                 col2,
                 col3,
                 col4
            FROM temptable2;
       DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cursor) ;

    END;
```

As you can see , that there is two temp tables getting used in this stored procedure, how I can remove the dependency of temp tables, can rewrite the whole stored procedure without temp tables

I don't need full code, maybe a pseudo code to adjust the **last delete and If logic.**

I was trying like a big select query but its not very convenient to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query and see if able to achieve same functionality :

```
 IF NVL(inputVariable1 , 0) = 1 THEN 
  OPEN  v_cursor FOR
 select col1,col2,NVL(col1,0) col3,col4
 from TABLE1
 JOIN TABLE 2 
 ON TABLE2.col1=TABLE1.COL1
 AND (TABLE2.COL4 NOT IN ('logic2','logic3') OR TABLE2.COL4 IS NOT NULL)
 AND col1!= 'logic4';
 DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cursor) ;
 END IF;
```